# Cannot Set UID on Shell Scripts

Tags: linux, iptables, suid

Can anyone help me find out what is going on here?  I have some rules set up tracking packet counts.  When I run the following script as root:

```
#!/bin/bash
iptables -t mangle -xnvL
```

I get the output I expect:

```
//snip
233203 199929802 MARK  //blah blah blah
//snip
```

However, I want to run this as part of cacti, which runs as apache.  Now apache can't run iptables, **which is why I have the script.  I set it up as SUID root**:

```
-rwsr-sr-x 1 root root   37 May 14 23:06 iptables_packet_report.sh
```

But then I get this output:

```
server # sudo -u apache ./iptables_packet_report.sh
iptables v1.4.2: can't initialize iptables table `mangle': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

Obviously my kernel is fine, and the fact that I'm running it as non-root is messing something up, but I don't understand why.  I did double check the SUID with [the demonstration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid#Demonstration and confirmed it was working.

```
server # sudo -u apache ./printid
Real UID  = 81
Effective UID = 0
Real GID  = 81
Effective GID = 0
```

My end goal is to get the output of iptables -t mangle -xnvL while running as apache so I can use cacti to graph it all nicely.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You cannot use SUID root for shell scripts. Only real programs can be SUID root, shell scripts start with "#!" and the interpreter would have to run SUID and that does not work for some reason I didn't know

Take a look at sudo and install it! Edit /etc/sudoerrs, add a line like this:

```
www-data        ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/sbin/iptables_packet_report.sh
```

Then just run

```
sudo /usr/local/sbin/iptables_packet_report.sh
```

from your code.

It should then not ask for the password, but evaluate the process automatically.

I'm quite sure that your error messages would also happen if you manually su into www-data and run it manually

Answer (score 13):

As Christian indicated my problem was that I was trying to SUID on a shell script.  [As explained here](http://ns2.deware.com:8000/info/oreilly/networking/puis/ch05_05.htm) setting SUID on a shell script is a very bad idea:

> executing a shell script under UNIX involves a two-step process: when the kernel determines that a shell script is about to be run, it first starts up a SUID copy of the shell interpreter, then the shell interpreter begins executing the shell script. Because these two operations are performed in two discrete steps, you can interrupt the kernel after the first step and switch the file that the shell interpreter is about to execute. In this fashion, an attacker could get the computer to execute any shell script of his or her choosing

Because of this, many modern linux distros ignore SUID shell scripts, including gentoo which I was using.  I was able to edit the sudoers file and got it working.

Comment: Fantastic answer!

Comment: anyone know if this is true for Solaris 10?

Answer (score 3):

I think christian's solution is best, but if you really wanted to, you can compile the script using [shc](http://www.datsi.fi.upm.es/~frosal/) and then setuid root on the compiled program.